# How to show image border in UIscrollview in xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, xcode4.5, css

i have one scrollview and in that am showing images dynamically with the for loop...now i want to make the scroll view images with its border..i am totally new in this xcode environment.i googled the things but cant understand how it will done..my code is as follows

```
scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
            for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {
                UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+0, 0, 320, 460)];
                [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n5%d.png",i]]];
                [scr addSubview:image];
                x+=320;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.delegate = self;
                image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [image addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
            }
            _detailDescriptionLabel.text=@"Bhavik";
            [self.view addSubview:scr];
             self.title=@"krish";
            scr.pagingEnabled=YES;
            scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 300);
```

Can anyone Give me Suggestion with some explanation so it will help in future too..

Comment: do you want to add border to the imageview?

Comment: yes i want to add border to UIImageView

Comment: then Rajan's answer will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // *** To add Framework ***
// Step 1 : Select your project From Navigation Panel on the left side
// Step 2 : On the Right Panel you will get details, Select Summery tab if not selected
// Step 3 : Scroll Down, you will find "Linked frameworks and Libraries", expand it.
// Step 4 : Press "+" button to add framework, Pick "QuartzCore.framework" framework from list and ADD it.

// Now import it to your file and do following code to add border

// First of all add QuartzCore.framework,
// Then import #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  your file

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+0, 0, 320, 460)];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n5%d.png",i]]];

// Set border color and width of image
[image.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[image.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];

[scr addSubview:image];
```

Comment: hmmm....thats great help...answer with good explanation..thank you

Comment: Thank you bhavik. Feel free to ask any of your queries.

Comment: oh.thanx...u r from Ahmedabad too..thats gr8?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in this manner :

```
//you need this import
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Comment: oh ok...i just tried earlier...but forget to import the above header file..silly mistakes...just started to development on iOS earlier..

Comment: @BhavikKama Enjoy the party !

Comment: can u please tell me more about this border..if i want to use shadows and all that?

Comment: @BhavikKama Use Google, Everything is already available on StackOverflow :) Check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc]init];
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

before import `#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>` framework.

Answer (score 1):

For give **Border** Of `UIImageView`.

Add `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` fram work.

```
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0; // set as you want.
imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor; // set color as you want.
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; // set as you want.
```